# aligning view top to the bottom of another view inside vertical stackview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I have a label and image attached in a vertical stack view. I want them to be centered to the stack view, but not larger. I also want the top of the label to be aligned to the bottom of the image.

I tried those constraints:

[image: screenshot]

But the label is stuck to the bottom of the stack view.

I also tried:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView,
    attribute: .top,
    relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
    toItem: contentView,
    attribute: .top,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView,
    attribute: .bottom,
    relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
    toItem: contentView,
    attribute: .bottom,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView,
    attribute: .left,
    relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
    toItem: contentView,
    attribute: .left,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView,
    attribute: .right,
    relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
    toItem: contentView,
    attribute: .right,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView,
    attribute: .centerX,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: contentView,
    attribute: .centerX,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView,
    attribute: .centerY,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: contentView,
    attribute: .centerY,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
    attribute: .height,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: stackView,
    attribute: .height,
    multiplier: 0.5,
    constant: 0).isActive = true
```

But now the image top is stuck to the top of the content view top, and the label bottom is stuck to the bottom of the content view bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIStackView` ***arranges its subviews***.

In your case, you have a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` as arranged subviews of a vertical stack view. So, the label will *always* be below the image view.

I'm assuming you have additional views to add to the stack view -- if so,

- To get the label "top-aligned" with the image view, embed both the label and the image view in a new `UIView`, set the constraints to pin the label to the top, then add that `UIView` to your stack view.

If not,

- You probably don't want to use the stack view at all.